# Numbering pages in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I can number the pages just fine using the .Pagesetup object. I can use the .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter to skip numbering the first page, but I also have an index, which I do not want to be numbered, how do I start numbering on the 3rd page?

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each ws In Worksheets
    ws.PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = True
    ws.PageSetup.RightFooter = "Page " & "&P" & " of " + "&N"
                                   
Next ws
Set ws = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: `ws.PageSetup.FirstPageNumber = 3`

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad  ws.PageSetup.FirstPageNumber = 3 just sets 2nd page to "page 3 of x" instead of 'page 2 of x".

Comment: I also noticed that once the page numbering is set in VBA, it sets it for the entire Workbook. In other words, it shows in the UI after running it in VBA once, so changing the VBA can get overridden by the settings in the UI.